# Is there an appropriate name for a “middle” table that only stores foreign keys of other tables?

Tags: database-design

[image]

Right now I am designing a new database for our family business. I have a few tables like in the image above, where the table only contains two foreign keys in order to represent an association between two records in two different tables.

Ex: `transaction_id` `123` contains the purchase of `membership_id` `100`.

Is there a proper naming convention or a word for tables like this? For now I have been using the word "index" as a placeholder, but I am not sure if this word is appropriate.

Comment: **[On the troubles of naming and terminology](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6582)**

Comment: It's called an XRef (cross reference) table.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this issue: https://world.hey.com/jdmo/how-to-name-your-junction-tables-3735fdc9

Comment: Each transaction really has 0-to-N memberships ? If each transaction can have one membership at most, then adding membership_id in transaction table as a foreign key would be enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The proper term is [associative table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity), though most often I've heard it called is a `Linker` table.

Typically this table is used to support a many-to-many relationship.

As for a naming convention, that would be up to you, though I will usually just pluralize the second name, in your example I would use `TransactionMemberships`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I will be using `linker` in my names. Thank you.

Comment: "join table" is also quite common and is used (for example) in the standard Java persistence APIs (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/JoinTable.html) to refer to such a table.

Comment: The term I've seen is "junction table".

Comment: Or "intersection table"

Answer (score 2):

### Join table

is the term I have most commonly heard being used.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen it done as MembershipXTransaction (pronounced Membership by Transaction)

Answer (score 1):

One other approach you should consider:

Name tables for what each record in the table represents.  **Use real world/business appropriate terminology as much as possible.**  This makes it easier for developers and business people to discuss what is in the database.

In your case, this gives you:

- **Membership** - Data about memberships
- **Transactions** - Data about transactions
- **Membership Transaction** - Data about the interaction of memberships and transactions.  This may only be the fact that the two are linked in a many-to-many relationship, but there are often other attributes of associative entities as well.

Note that simply slapping the names of the two tables on either end of a many-to-many relationship should not be your default choice.  It often works out that this is the most appropriate option, but sometimes there are other names that better reflect real business terminology.  For example: `USER` many-to-many with `ROLE` may be called `ROLE_MEMBER`.